# Return images on a CURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL to load a web page and return it onto a page on my server. However when the page is returned there are no images showing as they are linked using href="/image.png" etc.... Is there a way using CURL to add the url to any link that starts href="/

```
function pull_html($url, $device)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($device == 'iPhone'){
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25');
    }elseif($device == 'iPad'){
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25');
    }
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking you will use this for only one domain. Before curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); use if (strpos("http", $url) === FALSE) $url = "http ://domainname.com" . $url; You would have to modify these conditions based on your input urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple `str_replace()`

```
return str_replace('href="/', 'href="'.$url.'/', curl_exec($ch));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php